# how to scrape with shell script with advanced dom handling and cient side javascript processing

Tags: java, javascript, shell, web

I have site which uses client side validation and few more process like fetching data form other site like From client side. I have done it with vb in windows (third party Apps Not allowed). Now i want to start writing the same for shell. because i am left with wget in shell that dont process javascript on client side. so some better app inbuilt with Shell or even java with librariers should be fine.

a simple page get function used in vb. so all the webpage content after processed on client side will be downloaded..

```
Function IEGetPage(URL)
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Navigate URL
  Do While IE.Busy
  Loop
  IEGetPage = IE.Document.Body.innerHTML
  IE.Stop
  IE.Quit
End Function
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). This allows you to run JavaScript in a browser-like-environment from a Linux command-line shell.  For example you can use code something like this to grab an HTML page and analyze its DOM:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        ... handle error ...
    } else {
        ... = page.evaluate(function () {
            .. do something with document ...
        });
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Sorry Eamonn, I missed out a point. this is shell and i have to use only Wget. so the best way to get a browser like Env is by unis JAVA libraries and do it.. will try on that. Thanks For tht reply.!!